# Exporting Vim folds?

Tags: vim, folding

How can I export vim folds from a file, so that I can transfer it to a different machine?

For example say I create the folds in a file and save it on a local machine - where does the "folding" metadata go? Can I just copy it to another machine, or must I manually recreate the folds again?

EDIT: Hm, I've noticed this might be a duplicate question, but still there is not answer as to how to save the fold information WITHOUT modifying the source file.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Save your session with the `:mksession` command, and restore it with `vim -S Session.vim`. The session file will restore almost everything, including folds (though changes to the file will mess it up).

That works if you must use manual folds, but it's really a lot easier to use one of the automatic fold methods — investigate `indent`, `syntax`, and `expr`, and look for syntax files that fully support folding.

Comment: So you mean it stores a Session.vim file somewhere? Where?

Comment: Current directory, or anywhere you want. All there in the manual.

Comment: Since I usually launch gvim from a desktop icon, an alternative way to load the session file is to `:source Session.vim` once in the editor.  (My usage is usually `:mks ~/properties.vim` at night and `:so ~/properties.vim` if I'm working on the properties system; a convenient name to remember what I was doing...)

Answer (score 2):

Ok I've figured out a relatively painless way of doing it. This does require some change to the source file however.

First, set the fold-marker to be java style /** comment **/ markers:

```
:set foldmethod=marker
:set foldmarker=/\*\*,\*\*/
```

then inside my source any time I want a fold I just type:

```
/** This is the title of the section */
Some stuff goes here blah
...
//the line below "ends" the fold by double star
/* **/
```

This produces folds just as I expect them and is much easier to deal with than the "dynamic" or visual folding.